# Update css property of a child element in specific div

Tags: html, css, jsp, styles

I have 2 different div containers in my same jsp file for which i dont have access to edit.

--Div 1

```
<div class="mar-t40 alignRight">
    <img id="ts_fclogoBox" alt="Logo" src="{{imgPath}}/content/dam/Logo.png" />
</div>
```

--Div 2

```
<div class="alignRight">
    <img id="ts_fclogoBox" alt="Logo" src="{{imgPath}}/content/dam/Logo.png" />
</div>
```

Now i need to apply the below css only to ts_fclogoBox present inside DIV 2. Is it possible to achieve it without editing the jsp file ?

```
#ts_fclogoBox {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

I feel that is impossible but just wanted to see whether is there some way.

Comment: you cant use same id for two different elements ID's are unique if you use same ID's only that id will get affected which will be found by DOM first

Comment: As the previous comment points out, you shouldn't use same ID for two elements in same page. I also think that the answers have looked too literally and assumed the 2nd `div` to be the 2nd child which may not always be the case. If it is not always the second child then the method used in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e9bzj4np/) would help. If it meets your need then I will post as answer.

Comment: @Harry: perfect answer please post it as an answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class and ids to avoid confusion with other divs

```
div.alignRight:nth-child(2) img#ts_fclogoBox{
  margin-left:-15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can acheive that by using child selector in css3**

```
div:nth-child(2) img {
     margin-left: -15px;
}
```